# bash script with kdialog not running from cron

Tags: bash, cron

I am trying to run a bash script from cron, but nothing seems to work.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
printf '%s' $(date) '_END' >> battery_log.txt
export DISPLAY=:0
kdialog --msgbox "$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0| grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage")"
```

crontab (as sudo):

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/king/Scripts
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  * *   *   *   * bash /home/king/Scripts/my_battery_script
```

I have checked to make sure:

```
the script is executable
root user owns the script
I can run the script from within a shell using ./my_battery_script
I can run other bash scripts from within cron (I created a test script that wrote to a text file). Worked fine
kdelibs-full is installed
```

Why wont this script run?

**Edit: More details**

Running on Linux Mint 17.3

kernel: 3.19.0-32-generic

what I expect to happen: when timer fires in cron it launches the script (as root). The script uses its own display (not sure of the term) based on the DISPLAY variable (or so I read on other forums) to display a battery message

---

Logs from the script's actual execution follow:

```
++ date 
+ printf %s Mon Jan 11 22:29:01 EST 2016 _END 
MonJan1122:29:01EST2016_END+ export DISPLAY=:0 
+ DISPLAY=:0 
++ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0 
++ grep -E 'state|to\ full|percentage' 
++ cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp 
++ awk '{print "deg C: "$1/1000}' 
+ /usr/bin/kdialog --msgbox ' state: discharging 
percentage: 58% \n cpu temp: deg C: 44.5' 
No protocol specified 
kdialog: cannot connect to X server :0
```

Comment: why use `#!/bin/sh` when you can use `#!/bin/bash`? I don't think that will solve your problem but what OS are you using? Older Unixn may not support `PATH=...` in crontab, but if you're on Linux, that shouldn't be an issue. Why not add full path to `kdialog`. Also isn't that an interactive program using a windowing program? What do you expect to happen, from a program that was not launched from a user session? Who's session do you think `root` will take over to display that output? I don't have your environment, so I can't go further to help with this. Good luck! (Edit your Q w more details).

Comment: DISPLAY isn't enough for modern X systems -- you also need authentication (Xauthority).

Comment: Redirect your script's stderr to a log file, and include its contents in your question. That is: `exec 2>/path/to/file.log` as (say) the second line or so. You could also `exec 2>>battery_log.txt`, and then anything you echo or print `>&2` will go there without the overhead of reopening the file for that single command.

Comment: (...and having your shebang and manual shell invocation inconsistent is, as shellter says, bad practice; use the same shell for both -- `bash` and `/bin/sh` are **not the same shell** -- or else your script can behave differently depending on how it's started).

Comment: Which file do I put that line in? the crontab, or can I redirect the output from within the script itself?

Comment: From within the script itself.

Comment: That said, I'd almost put money on it being an Xauthority problem. It's literally been close to 30 years since systems were so insecure out-of-the-box you could just set DISPLAY and have that be enough to run an application on a different user's X server.

Comment: ...though, well, you wouldn't have any problems with Xauthority if you *weren't* trying to have root's cron (as opposed to a cron instance running as the same user owning the X session) doing this.

Comment: ...if I'm right, by the way, your correct answer is as given in http://superuser.com/a/598091/31769, and this question is a duplicate.

Comment: I have no problem switching the user by to me, I just thought switching it to root might help

Comment: Still waiting to see the log edited in.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I have waited on my end, but the script does not appear to be running at all (no log output). Should I run it manually in terminal?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100430/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-rilcon42).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> + /usr/bin/kdialog --msgbox ' state: discharging 
> percentage: 58% \n cpu temp: deg C: 44.5' 
> No protocol specified 
> kdialog: cannot connect to X server :0
> ```

Assuming that you actually have an X server running for display 0, this typically means that you have an OS-level security measure preventing root from accessing that display.

The easy answer here is to run this cron job under your user account, rather than as root.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add path to kdialog in your script, looks like command not found

Comment: How do I find the path to the kdialog install location?

Comment: @Rilcon42, `type kdialog`. (There's also the older external command `which`, but `type` more accurately shows what your shell would actually do, even if there are aliases/functions/etc involved).

Comment: locate kdialog or find . -name "kdialog"

Comment: @LevBystritskiy, hardly necessary if the OP can run the command inside their X session (outside cron) successfully -- we already know it's in their user account's PATH in that case, so they can interactively use `type` or `which` while in that session.